# How to write choices(clicks) to file

Tags: python, html, image, user-interface, tkinter

I have and array of arrays of jpgs and an array with the respective ids(from the sqlite db (urls to jpgs ... [[http://xxxxx.xxx/xxx.jpg]]), each element (array of jpgs) is from one or more themes.

What's the easies way to write to file the choice the user makes (thinking of jinja2 template with small images and a few buttons in front with the themes).

I don't mind if it only write something like num;them (i can make the update to the sqlite db)

I think it could be done with php, but i wich there was a way to do this locally.

Is it easy in tkinter? 
Is javascript able to write to file (isn't it in a sandbox?)?

GUI or html?

How would you tackle this?

Comment: What the heck are you talking about?

Comment: You go to the desert, do the a special dance and wait for the gods to answer.

Comment: easiest way to write choices from html to file without php (on simple ubuntu pc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, understand that when you're dealing with a controller action (the code that returns the Jinja2 template and does the querying of your database), you can carry out any kind of action on the server-side that Python (or whatever your server-side language may be) can do.  Of course Python can write to a file; this is covered [extensively](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in the documentation.  I would prefer to keep this kind of data in a database table, however, because it screams “data set that you want to analyze later.”  Thus, there are two bits of information you need to track:  **user-id** and **choice**.  You might also want to track **choice sequence**, since SQL doesn't have built-in sequentiality.

Let's say you're giving a user two choices on each page.

1. Determine a **user-id**.  This could
   be done by using a session id.
2. Display a choice to the user.
3. Write the choice number (1 or 2, for
   example), along with the user ID and
   the choice's position in the
   sequence, to the database.
4. Repeat until you're finished,
   incrementing the choice's position
   in the sequence each time.

Honestly, if I'm understanding your question correctly, this is a very simple problem.  When you're approaching something like this, try sitting down and writing what you need to track on paper.  Usually, there will be no more than a few key points that need tracking, and you can then approach it as a problem of how to store three (or four, or five) values rather than as a monolithic and unapproachable question.

Comment: Thanx.. I don't need to track the user id(but your algorithm is great thnx). And sorry for the "monolithic and unapproachable question"